# I am able to curl to node.js server but unable to http request from javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-cordova

At this moment I am able to do `curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8081/flower` in my command prompt and receive my JSON like I was expecting.

However, whenever I try to do the same GET request to the same exact URL from my code, I get undefined in every way I try. Below is my code for javascript and node.js. I would like to save the `responseText` to a global variable to be able to be saved as an array.

This is my HTTP request to pull the JSON request from the server:

```
function apiCall() {

 var menuRqst = new XMLHttpRequest;
    menuRqst.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/flower', true);
    menuRqst.send();
    menuRqst.addEventListener('readystatechange', processRequest, false);
    function processRequest(d) {
        if (menuRqst.readyState === 4 && menuRqst.status === 200) {
            var flowResponse = menuRqst.responseText;
            return flowResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my node.js where I can `curl -X GET 127.0.0.1:8081/flower` and receive the data found in flower.JSON as a response:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

app.get('/flower', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "flower.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        res.end(data);
    });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: the issue is `CORS` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS and the answer is https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: If I were to add jquery to my cordova application would I be able to skip having to setup cors? or is that a necessity for any http requests. Sorry I'm so new to server side development.

Comment: CORS is handled on the server - so, change the server so it sends CORS headers.,There's no library or hacks on the client that can bypass that - except maybe use a browser from the 1990's

Comment: actually, when I said "the problem is CORS" I could be mistaken - I'm assuming the page is loaded using a different "server", seeing as you specify protocol and IP in the request

Comment: Well both the application and server projects are open in visual studio next to each other. That's why I was assuming I could test the http protocols locally similar to how I can browse to C:\etc.\index.html, but even though they are both on the same machine they recognize as different domains?

Comment: Oh so with node.js I would implement the CORS lib to the server side not the application side.
EDIT: I am using Apache Cordova for the application, and Node.js for the server, seperate folders, both opened under the same project/solution in visual studio. I browse my Chrome to c:\root\index.html, and I refresh the page to check changes. I have visualstudio running the node.js server to see when I get bounce backs.

Comment: if anything is different ... protocol (http vs https), domain/IP or port (8080 vs 8081) then it is not same domain

Comment: I have installed cors into npm with "npm install cors", however when I try to run my nodejs server with 
var cors = require('cors');
added, the nodejs server opens node.js command prompt, loads for a second than crashes.

Comment: `var cors = require('cors');` isn't enough

Comment: `//app.use(cors())` that's a comment

Comment: Should that be enough to cause my server to crash?

Comment: I know both those are commented out, if I add either one or both the server crashes

Comment: I'm not sure how to paste the code in here so it looks neat, It turns into a paragraph

Comment: if it crashes when you `app.use(cors())` then perhaps you're doing something else wrong - it's hard to know because "it crashes" provides not information, whereas "it crashes with Error xyz, and here's the whole error trace"  makes it easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191825/discussion-between-devin-b-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: Okay so I can see that I am only opening the http request as far as readystate shows.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, I think with help from cors and I also merged the cordova project into the node.js project. I was able to successfully achieve this with this code.
Javascript:

```
    function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: I also made the node.js server to display my apache cordova on the webserver. this drastically helped in delpoyment time in comparison to deploying to emulated android

Answer (score -1):

It's all about asynchrony. `apiCall` is not returning anything.

Also, what's more you should find a way to prepare the response when is ready, probably wrapping a `Promise` at the start of `apiCall`.

Also, if this is browser code, you may want to try out `fetch` and use `async/await`.

With fetch:

```
async function apiCall () {
  const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8081/flower');
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();
  return jsonResponse
}
```

Comment: I think I have issues with this route for the reason I am using the JavaScript in Apache Cordova application wrapper, I have tried and I receive [OBJECT PROMISED]

Comment: yes @DevinB - you would, since an async function returns an Promise - using fetch just makes the request asynchronous using Promises, rather than asynchronous and using events - so, really, if you don't understand asynchrony then this answer won't be of any use either - besides, the code in the question is fundamentally wrong with its return statement

Comment: `return jsonResponse()` no, `jsonResponse` will be an Object, not a Function